# SQL command not ended properly error; trying to update information with a join

Tags: sql, oracle

```
UPDATE A
SET A.email_from = B.new_email_from
FROM email_list A 
INNER JOIN update B 
    ON A.email_subject = B.email_subject 
WHERE A.process = B.process;
```

I am trying to update a table with updated information that another table contains. I'm not sure why it keeps giving me this error.

`ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Most databases do not support this syntax.

Comment: What error are you getting? The text from your question title?

Comment: isn't update a reserved word, whatever sql database you're using ? What if you're escaping it with `'` or `\`` or whatever the system you're using use to escape table name

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's an Oracle database, my bad.

Comment: @Shawn ORA-00933

Comment: The `SET A.email_from = ` should be followed by an expression, the keyword `DEFAULT`, or a `(subquery)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `MERGE` will do

```
MERGE INTO a 
USING b 
ON ( a.email_subject = b.email_subject ) 
WHEN matched THEN 
  UPDATE SET a.email_from = b.new_email_from 
WHERE a.process = b.process;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid syntax for Oracle. It should be much simpler to do an `UPDATE` on a `JOIN`, but it is what it is.

Try something like:

```
UPDATE 
  ( 
    SELECT A.email_from, B.new_email_from
    FROM email_list A 
    INNER JOIN update B ON A.email_subject = B.email_subject 
        AND A.process = B.process
) s1
SET s1.email_from = s1.new_email_from
```

Comment: With this I am getting an error ORA-00903, saying update is not a valid table name.

Comment: Maybe try a `MERGE`. What version of Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @RemoveBeforeFight,

Please try updating using correlated sub query.

```
update a set A.email_from = (
  select B.new_email_from 
    from update B 
    where a.email_subject = b.email_subject 
    and A.process = B.process
);
```